# Is the symplectomorphism group of a compact manifold a tame Fréchet Lie subgroup of $\operatorname{Diff}(X)$?

Tags: lie-groups, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, frechet-manifold

In the famous paper [Hamilton, Richard S.  The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser.
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)  7  (1982),  no. 1, 65–222](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2), Hamilton introduced the category of tame Fréchet Lie groups and showed that for a compact symplectic manifold $(X,\omega)$, the identity component $\operatorname{Diff}_0(X)$ is a tame Fréchet Lie group whose action on the space of symplectic forms isotopic to $\omega$ is tame. Then he asked (Problem 2.5.5) whether the stabilizer $\operatorname{Diff}_\omega(X)\cap\operatorname{Diff}_0(X)$ is a tame Lie subgroup. I have two questions:

1. Since the symplectomorphism group $\operatorname{Diff}_\omega(X)$ is modelled on the subspace of closed 1-forms (using Weinstein's trick), is it true that it is itself a tame Fréchet Lie group? This may be well known, but I was not able to find references.
2. Is the answer to Hamilton's Problem 2.5.5 known? Again, any reference would be appreciated.